# Noting quantiles in chi-squared distribution

Tags: quantile, chi-squared

Is there a "proper way" (a commonly accepted way) to note the quantiles of a Chi-squared distribution ?

I found this sentence, rather complicated, in Wikipedia (*Chi-squared_distribution*):

"the χ2 ICDF for p = 0.05 and df = 7 yields 14.06714 ≈ 14.07"

For a normal distribution, the Greek letter ***phi***(uppercase) is commonly used. And for Chi-squared distribution ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, most CDF are shortened either with a latin-alphabet letter or a greek letter, together with the value of the variables the function takes.
For instance: F(0.95,8,8) for the F-Snedecor distribution, with 0.95 cumulative probability, 8 degrees of freedom for the first input and 8 for the second. 

t(0.95,10) for t-student distribution and so on...
Chi-Square is usually represented with the greek letter followed by its cumulative probability and its degrees of freedom. X(0.95,degrees_of_freedom).
Sometimes a final hyperparameter it's passed, to express if it's right-tailed or left-tailed.
I think this should be moved to stats or math exchange though.